# How to set struts2 action's variable from within async block?

Tags: java, asynchronous, servlets, struts2, servlet-3.0

I am trying to run `struts2` `async` action.

Is there a way to set action's variables form async context?

In the code below `cust1List` is set inside `async` block but outside the block it remains `null`.

**web.xml:**

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
        org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter
    </filter-class>
    <async-supported>true</async-supported>
</filter>
```

**Action code:**

```
public class GenerateAsynctResult extends ActionSupport {
        private ArrayList cust1List;
         public String execute() {
          HttpServletRequest req = ServletActionContext.getRequest();
          HttpServletResponse res = ServletActionContext.getResponse();

          final AsyncContext asyncContext = req.startAsync(req, res);
          asyncContext.start(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
              try {
                // doing some work asynchronously ...
                ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
                list.add("A");
                list.add("B");
                list.add("C");
                setCust1List(list);
                //this will print out "C"
                System.out.println(cust1List.get(2));
              }
              finally {
                asyncContext.complete();
              }
            }
          });
        //this will throw null pointer exception cause cust1List is null
        System.out.println("b4 success" + cust1List.get(2));
        return Action.SUCCESS;
        }

       public ArrayList getCust1List() {
            return cust1List;
        }

        public void setCust1List(ArrayList cust1List) {
            this.cust1List = cust1List;
        }
    }
```

Any ideas on how to overcome this?

Thanks.

Comment: `cust2List` is null because you never defined it, at least not in that example. Could you check your example again?

Comment: @beendr just a typo in above example - I meant `cust1List` (in my real code I have both `cust2List` and `cust1List`). Thanks for the correction. However, the question remains the same...